# ERROR:Attempted import error: 'Prompt' is not exported from 'react-router'

Tags: react-router-dom, prompt

When I processed project with command:'npm start',I got the following error message,how to resolve the error?
./node_modules/react-router-dom/esm/react-router-dom.js
Attempted import error: 'Prompt' is not exported from 'react-router'.

Comment: Seems you've updated to `react-router-dom` version 6, which no longer exports a `Prompt` component nor was it replaced by anything. You can either revert back to version 5, or manage blocking navigation with a prompt using a custom history object and using that to block when the component is unmounting.